# Compare two data-frames and removes rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two date-frames in the following format. df-a:

```
         ID         Start_Date     End_Date 
1        cd2        2020-06-01     2020-06-09              
2        cd2        2020-06-24     2020-07-21             
3        cd56       2020-06-10     2020-07-03              
4        cd915      2020-04-28     2020-07-21              
5        cd103      2020-04-13     2020-04-24
```

and df-b:

```
         ID         Date
1        cd2        2020-05-12                   
2        cd2        2020-04-12                  
3        cd2        2020-06-29                  
4        cd15       2020-04-28                   
5        cd193      2020-04-13
```

I need to discard all rows for all IDs in df-b where they fall in various date ranges for the same ID in df-a. I.e ANSWER

```
         ID         Date
1        cd2        2020-05-12                   
2        cd2        2020-04-12                  
                
4        cd15       2020-04-28                   
5        cd193      2020-04-13
```

as ID cd2 is the only ID that matches in df-a with one date that fall within cd2's date ranges from df-a.

Sorry for the long-winded question. First time posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best to understand your question, however I am confused by your sample answer. 
None of the IDs in df-b should be removed. Even for row 3 of df-b, the date (2020-06-10) does not fall in the range of any start/end dates for ID cd2 in df-a.

 
I did set up a similar example to what you provided with df-a being:

```py
    ID       Start_Date    End_Date
0   cd2      2020-06-01    2020-06-11
1   cd2      2020-06-24    2020-07-21
2   cd56     2020-06-10    2020-07-03
3   cd915    2020-04-28    2020-07-21
4   cd103    2020-04-13    2020-04-24
```

and df-b being:

```py
    ID      Date
0   cd2     2020-05-12
1   cd2     2020-04-12
2   cd2     2020-06-10
3   cd15    2020-04-28
4   cd193   2020-04-13
```

With this example, row 2 (0-based) of df-b should be removed since 2020-06-10 falls between 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-11 in row 0 of df-a.

**Here's my code for doing the row deletions**

```py
df_c = df_b.copy()

for i in range(df_c.shape[0]):
    currentID = df_c.ID[i]
    currentDate = df_c.Date[i]
    df_a_entriesForCurrentID = df_a.loc[df_a.ID == currentID]
    
    for j in range(df_a_entriesForCurrentID.shape[0]):
        startDate = df_a_entriesForCurrentID.iloc[j,:].Start_Date
        endDate = df_a_entriesForCurrentID.iloc[j,:].End_Date
        
        if (startDate <= currentDate <= endDate):
            df_c = df_c.drop(i)
            print('dropped')
```

where df_c is the output DataFrame.

After running this, df_c should look like:

```py
    ID     Date
0   cd2    2020-05-12
1   cd2    2020-04-12
3   cd15   2020-04-28
4   cd193  2020-04-13
```

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry for the confusion , that is a typo and I have now changed the row 3 d df-b to the correct date. However, it appear you have understood the problem :)! thanks for your answer Jacob. This looks great, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Glad I could help! If my solution works, could you please give me an upvote :). Thanks!

Comment: Hi there @Jacob K, I tried up voting but I don't have enough rep yet :S. I actually have an additional question which you may be able to help me solve. Instead of removing the row from the dataset (df_b/df_c), i would like to concat the row with the columns from df_a to df_b/df_c. i.e 

` ID      Date      Start_Date    End_Date
0   cd2     2020-05-12   -     - 
1   cd2     2020-04-12    -     - 
2   cd2     2020-06-10  2020-06-01    2020-06-11
3   cd15    2020-04-28   -     - 
4   cd193   2020-04-13   -     -    `

Comment: @twilik I can take a look at that soon. Could you please create another question to help keep things organized though? Thanks!

Comment: here is a link to the new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552831/merge-two-data-frames-based-on-multiple-conditions